# Which one font awesome in react app using cdn or npm

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

im  really confused what is the best way to integrate fontawesome to reactjs web app using CDN or installing  NPM for production ecommerce i also use webpack for react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fontawesome npm package. When you use npm package, just used icons will add to your component. This help page size while loading.

**Step 1 )** Add packages with npm:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Or for free regular icons:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
```

**Step 2 )** Import fontawesome to your component:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
```

**Step 3 )** Import icon that you need:

```
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

**Step 4 )** Add jsx tag where you want in return function in component:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
```

Comment: Which one should i use for free icons step 1 or step 2

Comment: For free icons, do it step by step. All steps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest npm..
[react font awesome icon](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react)

Answer (score 1):

CDN is basically another request to some server. Since, your browser can run concurrently process only 5 requests using more cdn makes browser bit slower at first.

I prefer to use npm package for react